# Plesk notification email template in HTML?

Tags: template

Would i be able to use html in formatting notification emails in Plesk Penel?

Just that :)

Comment: Questions concerning the use of **shared web hosting by end users or resellers**, rather than the administration of web hosting, are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such ability.